# In OOP, is it faster to call a function to return a value, or by directly calling the value?

Tags: c++, oop, object

If I have a class `File`

```
class File {
    public:
        File(int length);
        getLength();  //returns length int value
        int length;
}
```

Between `File.value` (implying it's not private/anything else, so it can be accessed directly) and `File.getValue()`, what is the option which impacts performance less?

Comment: Lets not think about speed and instead think about encapsulation.  Should I be able to have direct access to `length`?  If so there is no reason to have a getter at all.  If I should not then use a getter.

Comment: Accessing a field directly costs slightly less, I think.

Comment: @arrowd a) It won't on any half-decent compiler. b) Thinking about such micro-optimization is the epitome of counterproductiveness

Comment: to the ones who downvote on such questions, can't you remember yourself being a beginner programmer?

Comment: If the body of the function is `{ return length; }` and the compiler cannot optimize that, I wouldn't trust it to optimize any other code either.

Comment: Once the optimizer's done with it, it looks about the same to me. A sampling of GCCs 4.8 through 7.3  with -O3 gives `mov edi, DWORD PTR [rdi]` for both unless I do stupid stuff.

Comment: The point of encapsulation is far more important than speed.  If an end-user can change `length` and negatively impact your code, it doesn't matter how fast it is.  Someone will break it.  And then blame you.

Comment: It was just a curiosity. I know that it's a 'micro-optimization' question.

Comment: @PasserBy I'd argue that a `call` of any calling convention takes more cycles than a `mov`.

Answer (score 3):

Without optimization the getter will cost more. A value can be accessed with a single 'mov' instruction, but a function call (for the getter) will need many more instructions (at least an additional 'call' and 'ret').

If you define your getter as 'inline' then most of the compilers will remove the function call and the performance will be the same as accessing the member variable directly. 'inline' methods and functions will most likely be implemented within the header file (because every translation unit needs access to the function source).

Most modern compiler will even inline getters which are not marked as 'inline' if optimizations are enabled. Some compilers will online remove the function call for calls from within the same module (.cpp file). At least Visual C++ removes the function call even if it is called from another module or even project if 'link time code generation' (LTCG) is active for both parts.

Note: Even if a modern compiler does not use the 'inline' keyword to decide if a method should be inlined, it still avoids the 'multiple definitions' linker error you normally get if you implement a method within a header file which is used from multiple modules.

There is a huge chance that, if public access to the member variable is ok for you, you do not need a getter (and/or a setter) at all.

Comment: "'inline' methods and functions must be implemented within the header file" - No. That's not correct. `inline` functions can be implemented outside the header - also remember LTO is a thing, and as far as optimizations go, `inline` is mostly ignored by modern compilers anyway; they'll inline or not based on their own analysis, not the `inline` keyword.

Comment: You are right. It makes sense if you have to use it from multiple modules, but sure you can declare an inline function from within a module. I think LTO is (a part of) LTCG in Visual C++.

Comment: `inline` is not for optimizing, but for allowing multiple identical definitions, so the compiler will have the source, and thus *might* inline. LTO obviates the need for it, aside from use in header-only libraries.

Comment: The original intent was to use it as a hint for the compiler/optimizer that "inline substitution of a function was preferred [...]". Even if modern compilers decide on their own it still serves this purpose at least in Visual C++.